# another mongo data format after update to php 7

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, php-7

We use Symfony2 / Doctrine / MongoDB. Previously on php 5 insert integer to mongo saved as "NumberLong". After updating to php7 and new `ext-mongodb` - integer saved as integer. In previous `ext-mongo` was class `MongoInt64` for saving in NumberLong, but now it deprecated.

How to save in format `NumberLong` in php7? It's need, because database used by other 3d party services.

Comment: Just force numberlong on your int NumberLong(your_int)

Comment: Just use integer field type, if you save long number, it will be saved in db as NumberLong, for ex.: `"someField": NumberLong("4294967295")`.

Comment: @malcolm need to save even small number (for example, "3") as NumberLong.